# Apache poi cloneSheet partly copying comments (comment is there but no drawing)?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI 4.1 and the cloneSheet() method on top of an XSSFWorkbook to clone a sheet. Unfortunately, comments seem to be properly cloned but without the underlying drawings.

Any code to remove comments from cells on newSheet result in a null pointer exception due to non-existing drawing object instances.

No comments are visible on the new sheet after opening the resulting file in Excel.

```
final Workbook wb = sourceSheet.getWorkbook();

// duplicate base sheet
Sheet newSheet = wb.cloneSheet(wb.getSheetIndex(sourceSheet));
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51559133/poi-3-17-creating-cell-comments-in-a-cloned-sheet-creates-inconsistent-xlsx. I don't think that there has much changed from `3.17` to `4.1.0` with this.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Thank you very much! João